# Green's theorem: what does closed path integral mean?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm studying green's theorem and having brief idea about this theorem.
but little bit confused with first example

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/GreensTheorem.aspx
(goes to example 1)

if you look at the example it said 
evaluate   $\int xy dx + x^2+y^2 dy$
where this equation came? and how this related with bottom picture?

Comment: Exactly what is your question? The example simply uses green theorem to compute a line integral over a triangular path as a double integral over the region bounded by the path. The equation $(xy)dx + (x^2+y^2) dy$ has nothing to do with the picture, the picture only shows the path or region of integration

Comment: then why they choose /$int xy dx + (x^2 + y^2) dy for?

Comment: Well it is an example, they could have choosen anything of the form $\int P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy$, it happens that with that particular example, by applying Greens theorem, the double integral that results is very easy to compute

Comment: are they choose  $\int xy dx + x^2+y^2 dy$  from the picture? I'm very confuse how they extract this equation and why they use it.  i do not understand they can choose anything. probably i'm missing something

Comment: No, **the picture is only to display the contour of integration**, it has nothing to do with the integrand. Let $C$ be the path define by the triangle with vertices $(0,0); (1,0)$ and $ (1,2)$, if $C^o$ denotes the region bounded by $C$, by Green's theorem 
$$
\int_C P(x,y) dx + Q(x,y) dy = \iint_{C^o} \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right)dA
$$ 
Since $C^o$ is the interior of the triangle $C$, in this case $\iint_{C^o} dA = \int_0^1\int_0^{2x} dy dx$. In your example you have that $P(x,y) = xy$  and $Q(x,y) =x^2+y^2 $